# Set default user variable in csh scripting

Tags: shell, csh

I am writing a csh shell script, `run` where the user is expected to pass a path into it as the `$1` variable. How can I determine if `$1` is missing and define a default value instead for it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
        dir='default' # argument not passed use default.
else
        dir=$1        # argument passed..use it.
fi

# use $dir 
ls $dir
```

Comment: That's Bourne and family. The question is tagged `[csh]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is know to work on tcsh version 6.15.00

```
#! /bin/csh

if( $#argv == 0 ) then
        set filename="(default file)"
else
    set filename=$argv[1]
endif

echo "The file is $filename."
```

**NOTE**
There is no standard with *csh* as there is with the POSIX shell; but at least basic `if-then-else` and `$#argv` should be portable.

**See Also**
[POSIX and Korn Shell Versus Other Shells](http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90046/ch15s03.html)
[Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.ooblick.com/text/CshProgrammingConsideredHarmful.html)
[Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: can I do this in one line ? because I need to use it in alias